# How to create a DataFrame of a single column from a list where the first element is the column name in python

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have the below data in a csv and I am trying to create a dataframe of 1 column by selecting each column from the csv at a time.

```
sv_m1   rev     ioip    
0       15.31   40      
0       64.9    0       
0       18.36   20      
0       62.85   0       
0       10.31   20      
0       12.84   10      
0       69.95   0       
0       32.81   20
```

The list that I get, the first value is the column name and remaining are values.

```
input_file = open('df_seg_sample.csv', 'r')
c_reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',')
#Read column
column = [x[1] for x in c_reader]
label = column[0]
column = column[1:]
df_column = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data = column,columns = label)
```

However this gives me an error:

```
  TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'sv_m1' was passed
```

core is actually the column name.

How can I create this df?
The column name of the df will be the first element in the list and all other items in the list will be the column values.

The reason for not using pandas.read_csv is: 
The dataframe is huge and hogs up a lot of memory. So I want to read in a column at a time, do some processing and write it to another csv.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: any reason not to read the csv with `pandas`, e.g. `pd.read_csv('df_seg_sample.csv')`

Comment: Hello @AChampion. The df is huge and uses a lot of memory if I store it all together in a df. So I want to read in a column at a time, do some processing and then move onto the next column. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @jezrael.. I am sorry.. There is no problem anywhere sir..I just loose track at times. I am sorry if you felt otherwise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jezrael.. Thanks.. Do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598383/process-subset-of-data-based-on-variable-type-in-python this question? In case yes it works for me. However I have posted only a small sample of data for reproducability.

Comment: I think with your sample data get error, i cannot run your sample.

Comment: @jezrael.. Update the question with code to generate data. Please check!

Comment: I change `df_column = df_data_sample` and run and get `ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series`. Do you use pandas `0.23.0` ?

Comment: I get error in `df_final[target_column] = df_target_attribute[[target_column]]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172047/discussion-between-shuvayan-das-and-jezrael).

Comment: My email is in my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) here with `usecols` parameter for filter second column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('df_seg_sample.csv', usecols=[1])
print (df)
     rev
0  15.31
1  64.90
2  18.36
3  62.85
4  10.31
5  12.84
6  69.95
7  32.81
```

But if want use your solution is necssary add `[]` for one item list for column name and use only `DataFrame` contructor:

```
data = [x[1] for x in c_reader]
print (data)
['rev', '15.31', '64.9', '18.36', '62.85', '10.31', '12.84', '69.95', '32.81']

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=[data[0]])
print (df)
     rev
0  15.31
1   64.9
2  18.36
3  62.85
4  10.31
5  12.84
6  69.95
7  32.81
```